# Installing Lakka on an old Macbook Pro

Tags: osx, openelec

I've been trying to get a USB with Lakka.img on it to boot on a 2011 Macbook Pro for the last few days now, and I'm not getting anywhere. I've used/tried to:

- Copy the image to the usb via the terminal with `dd` (OSX)
- Win32DiskImager
- Changing the extension to .iso manually and using Unetbootin/Rufus/Universal USB Installer

Is there something I'm missing? Also, sorry in advance if I'm posting this in the wrong SE. Cheers!

Comment: What is Lakka, what exact version is this? What exact errors do you see? I'm no Mac user, but is this already a (glorified) PC or some other architecture?

Comment: It's a distro for emulating retro games [based on OpenELEC and RetroArch](http://www.lakka.tv/doc/Home/). I don't see any errors, I'm just trying to get the usb to boot. And yeah, that's why I posted here instead of the apple SE.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Thinking about taking the plunge on an old Macbook, but don't want to start if it's hopeless.